# Ignorar .classpath e .project no GitHub

Tags: git, github

Não estou conseguindo ignorar os arquivos .classpath e .project no GitHub. Estes já estão no meu .gitignore porém após um tempo sempre acabam voltando. Estou utilizando o Eclipse + EGit.

Segue meu arquivo .gitignore

```
/bin
/null
/.settings

*.db
*.class
*.jar
*.war
*.ear
.classpath
/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
.project
/null/Documentos/indice-lucene/write.lock
/config.properties
```

Comment: `sempre acabam voltando`, ou seja, inicialmente você consegue ignorá-los?

Comment: Porque você não usou o mesmo padrão das outras extensões ignoradas, ou seja, `*.classpath` e `*.project`?

Comment: A principio sim, eu deleto os arquivos e continuo dando commit, após algum tempo eles estão lá novamente.

@MiguelAngelo usei, mas mudei pra ver se resolvia o problema.

Comment: Tem outras pessoas trabalhando no mesmo projeto? E o arquivo `.gitignore` está sendo comitado?

Comment: Não, somente eu. Sim, está.

Comment: Você está usando algum programa de versionamento, tipo GitExtensions, TortoiseGit, ou é git puro mesmo? É no windows?

Comment: Sim, estou usando Windows + Eclipse + EGit

Comment: Quando o git é "alterado automaticamente" o arquivo `.gitignore` fica como se tivesse alterações para commitar?

Comment: Outra coisa, o `.classpath` e o `.project` foram commitados alguma vez?

Comment: Sim, eles foram commitados no primeiro commit, mas então fiz a correção no .gitignore e deletei os arquivos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumindo que você tenha acidentalmente feito commit dos arquivos `.classpath` e `.project` eles continuarão sendo rastreados independentemente do arquivo `.gitignore`. Se esse for o caso faça o seguinte:

```
git rm --cached .project
git rm --cached .classpath
```

Corrija seu arquivo `.gitignore`, execute o `commit` e atualize seu projeto. Os arquivos `.classpath` e `.project` devem parar de serem rastreados.

---

**Fonte:** https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files

Comment: Já tentei fazer isso, acho que é algum problema no Eclipse ou no Egit. Troquei a IDE para IntelliJ e agora não tenho mais problemas com "lixo" sendo jogado para dentro do git.

Comment: IntelliJ é demais! Mesmo assim não consigo reproduzir seu problema no Eclipse (Kepler SR2). Tem alguma coisa (plugin, bugzinho na sua combinação de EGit e bridge com o Git, etc) fazendo o problema acontecer.

Comment: Se você conseguir fazer um pequeno repositório no GitHub e um zip do projeto local que está dando problema eu posso dar uma olhada, ou então você abre um bug diretamente para o pessoal do Eclipse: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/ (mas só abra se tiver 100% de certeza que dá para reproduzir em uma instalação atual limpa).

Comment: Ah, uma coisa... Eu não sei se interpretei sua questão corretamente. Se os arquivos `.classpath` e `.project` estão aparecendo somente na sua máquina isso é comportamento normal (o IDE vai continuar recriando os arquivos), o que não pode acontecer é esses arquivos continuarem sendo rastreados.

Comment: Infelizmente acabei desistindo do Eclipse e mudei de IDE. Mas acho que é sim algum bug no Egit, por que eu até fiz o commit inicial e esses arquivos subiram junto, depois os adicionei no .gitignore e deletei do git. Mas após alguns pushes eles voltavam pra lá.